# How to display Unique record number using sql?

Tags: mysql

I have student table

> ```
> id | name | zip 
> 1  | abc  | 1234
> 2  | xyz  | 4321
> 3  | cde  | 1234
> ```

And i want to only display unique zip code which is 4321. I don't want to display the 1 and 3 record number. So, how can i display the unique record only?

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: what did you try?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following query will give you all zip codes which don't appear in duplicate:

```
SELECT zip
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY zip
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
```

If you want to *also* get the full records then you can use the above as a subquery to filter the original table:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT zip
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY zip
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
) t2
    ON t1.zip = t2.zip
```

or this:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE zip IN
(
    SELECT zip
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY zip
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
)
```

Answer (score 1):

This will also work

```
select 
    id, name, zip
from
    (select 
        id, name, zip, count(zip) as countZip
    from
        student
    group by zip) as subq
where
    countZip = '1'
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a `DISTINCT` modifier that forces a select to show only one value for a column that may appear several times. In your case it would be:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ZIP
  FROM ...
```